# Uploaded file to shared drive cannot be updated because it cannot be found

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I am uploading files to a shared Google Drive via the Python module. That works fine. I can then change the permissions on the file. I am then trying to move the file to a folder on the shared Drive. Prior to attempting this, I check to see if the file exists. On the success of that check I have tried calling `service.files.update()` and `service.files.patch()` and get the same exception:

```
Error message: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Karg-secondary-logo-black.png'
```

In that same `except` I print out the following data:

```
    There was an error moving the file:
    File name: Karg-secondary-logo-black.png
    File id: 18-DjbDzAU4LnoHFxxxxxxxxxx
    Drive Id: 0AP0O9VQMoxxxxxxxxxx
    Destination folder id:  ['1uePl6bV9BtYEmS1xKh-xxxxxxxxx']
    Error message: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Karg-secondary-logo-black.png'
```

This matches the ids passed into the patch and update methods.

I've also manually verified that the file uploads successfully. The shared drive is empty except for these tests items and I clear it out (and the trash) each time I run the code.
[gdrive with items added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcQMT.png)

Here's my relevant code (with me trying the patch method. Update method is also there but commented out:

```
def uploadFileToGDrive(self, driveService, filename, filepath, mimetype, parentFolderId, driveId): 
    
    try: 

        #upload file to drive
        fileMetaData = {'name': filename, 'mimeType': mimetype, 'parents': [driveId]}
        media = MediaFileUpload(filepath, mimetype=mimetype)
        results = driveService.files().create(body=fileMetaData, media_body=media, fields='id, driveId, owners, originalFilename', supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
        fileId = results["id"]

        print(f'{cm.OKGREEN}The file: {filename} was uploaded to the Shared Google drive {results["driveId"]} and has the id # of {fileId}{cm.ENDC}')

        #edit permissions of file
        permResults = driveService.permissions().create(fileId=fileId, supportsAllDrives=True, body={"role": "reader", "type": "anyone"}).execute()

    except Exception as e:

        print(f"{cm.WARNING}There was an error uploading the file {filepath} to the folder {driveId} on GDrive\n{e}{cm.ENDC}")

    #check if uploaded file exists in drive
    dictResults = self.checkIfFileExists(driveService, fileId, mimetype, driveId)

    #move file if it exists
    if dictResults["success"] == True:

        try:

            #move file to parentFolder
            fileMetaData = {'name': filename, 'mimeType': mimetype, 'parents': [parentFolderId]}
            newMedia = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=mimetype, resumable=True)
            #moveResults = driveService.files().update(fileId=fileId, body=fileMetaData, media=newMedia, addParents=[parentFolderId], removeParents=[driveId], supportsAllDrives=True, includeItemsFromAllDrives=True).execute()
            results = driveService.files().patch(fileId=dictResults["file"]["id"], addParents=[parentFolderId], supportsAllDrives=True)

        except Exception as e:

            print(f'{cm.WARNING}There was an error moving the file:\n File name: {dictResults["file"]["name"]}\n File id: {dictResults["file"]["id"]}\nDirve Id: {driveId}\n Destination folder id:  {parentFolderId}\nError message: {e}{cm.ENDC}')

    else: 
        print(f"{cm.WARNING}Could not find the file {filename}.{cm.ENDC}")

def checkIfFileExists(self, driveService, fileId, mimetype, driveId):

    try: 

        bSuccess = False

        response = driveService.files().list(pageSize=100, fields="files(id, name)", includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, supportsAllDrives=True, corpora="drive", driveId=driveId).execute()
        lstFiles = response.get('files', [])

        myMatchedFile = None
        
        #see if our file id is in the list
        for thisItem in lstFiles: 
            if fileId == thisItem["id"]:
                bSuccess = True
                myMatchedFile = thisItem
                break

        return {"success": bSuccess, "file":myMatchedFile} 

    except Exception as e: 
        print(f'{cm.WARNING}There was an issue getting the file list from the drive {driveId}\n{e}{cm.ENDC}')
```

I'm running out of debug options. Hoping someone can help me find where I am going wrong here.